# What's the usage of getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) in DiffUtil.Callback

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-developer-api

[DiffUtil.Callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.Callback.html) has method

`getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition)`

> When areItemsTheSame(int, int) returns true for two items and areContentsTheSame(int, int) returns false for them, DiffUtil calls this method to get a payload about the change.
>
> For example, if you are using DiffUtil with RecyclerView, you can
> return the particular field that changed in the item and your
> ItemAnimator can use that information to run the correct animation.
>
> Default implementation returns null.

What profit of overriding this method?

How can I use it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's related to concept of Partial and Full binding in RecyclerView

[detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41173166/6484797)

Comment: It woul be better to read a newer answer in that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172427/need-an-explanation-why-recyclerview-adapter-notifyitemchangedint-position-obj.